# how to get the if else condition using filter operation of java stream?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, predicate

Question :
from the list of an integer get the square of odd number and half the even number and then return the list of value.

Ans : 1> i will write the logic and  if else condition inside the map() method.

```
List<Integer> output = intArray.stream().map(x-> {
                        if(x%2 ==0){
                            x=x/2;
                        }else{
                            x= x*x;
                        }
                     }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is their any better way to do this specially using **Filter**?

Comment: Is this code compiling? You are not returning anything. And reassigning the incoming parameter has no effect for the caller. [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: Filter is used to remove elements from a list. Since you want to perform operations on them, Map is the right way to go!

Comment: `map(x -> x%2 == 0? x/2: x*x)`

Answer (score 2):

#### Try using map:

```
map(x -> x % 2 == 0? x / 2: x * x);
```

Let me know if this works for you.
You can learn more about map and filter [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-map-filter-collect-of-stream-in-java-8#:%7E:text=map(Function%20mapper)%20takes%20a,one%20object%20to%20the%20other.)

Answer (score 0):

As you are transforming data (performing a math operation), you cannot use `Filter` here. `Filter` is used to filter out elements in your stream. For example if you only want to preserve the even numbers, you could use a `Filter`

What you need to use is the `Map`, as you already did. Do note that a map should always return data. Your code is missing this return statement.

To make it more readable, you could split your mapping logic in a method. This makes your stream easy to read and easy to follow (when you give the method a good name ofcourse).

### Code example

```
List<Integer> output = intArray.stream()
            .map(test::divideOrPow)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

private int divideOrPow(intx) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        return x / 2;
    } else {
        return x * x;
    }
}
```